# Multiple connections error

Tags: windows, networking

Trying to access **admin$** share on remote machine, I get this error:

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

However, **net use** reports no entries:

```
C:\Users\XXXX>net use
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.
```

Can it be that **admin$** doesn't exists on remote machine?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the remote machine?

Comment: @jftuga: I think it is "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a share does not exist, the server would return "Network name not found". What you are getting now means exactly that: there is another active connection.

It seems that *net use* only reports explicitly opened connections (`net use \\server\share` or mapped drives through GUI), but not implicit ones (established by simply opening a file or pipe). Use `netstat` to see if there are any active SMB connections, and check with Process Explorer for processes that hold open handles to files on network shares.

Comment: I tried TCPView and you are right, it has a connection established. The remote port is 445 (NetBios I think) and the process is System, so I can't close it. How to close a NetBios connection without `net use * /d`?

Comment: @Veehmot: Close any open files that are using the connection, and it will (*should*) go away within seconds. Again, Process Explorer's search function should help.

Comment: Nevermind, I used Right Click -> Close Connection and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Again i struggle with this problem...
There is lots of variations of this question across stackexchande sites...

So list of ways to deal with this:

1. "Credential manager" to clean old credentials
2. "net use" to list, and "net use * /delete" to remove everything
3. netstat for debugging (thanks @grawity)
4. connect to server by ip instead of it's name

Also, there is this feature, when Windows Explorer first uses local user credentials, allowing to enter correct credentials only if local credentials fail. This can give you quite a headache when server has that user or guest access, but you need to use another username.

UPD.
In my cause this behavior was caused by Windows update + legacy Group policy "Enable insecure guest logons". But without this group policy, no connections at all was possible to that server.